# OpenGL DSA and FBO

Tags: framebuffer, opengl-4

I upgraded my FBO code to use DSA (Direct Access State) features from OpenGL 4.5.

All is fine, but I still need to use glBindFramebuffer() before drawing. Is there something I missed ?

I was thinking about this call before drawing to my FBO.

```
glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffer(m_FBO, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
```

Then use this one to revert back to default framebuffer.

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
```

But it doesn't work. Should I still use glBindFramebuffer() ? And finally what is the use of glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffer() if so ?

I hardly found clear topics about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffer.xhtml) does not bind the frambuffer to the target. It only specifies the color buffer for a named framebuffer object.

See [OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification - 17.4.1 Selecting Buffers for Writing, p. 513](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> 17.4.1 Selecting Buffers for Writing
>
> The first such operation is controlling the color buffers into which each of the fragment color values is written. This is accomplished with either **DrawBuffer** or **DrawBuffers** commands described below.
>   The set of buffers of a framebuffer object to which fragment color zero is written is controlled with the commands
>
> ```
> void DrawBuffer( enum buf );
> void NamedFramebufferDrawBuffer( uint framebuffer, enum buf );
> ```
>
> For **DrawBuffer**, the framebuffer object is that bound to the DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER binding. For **NamedFramebufferDrawBuffer**, framebuffer is zero or the name of a framebuffer object. If framebuffer is zero, then the default draw framebuffer is affected.

See [OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification - 9.2 Binding and Managing Framebuffer Objects, p. 297](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> A framebuffer object is created by binding a name returned by **GenFramebuffers** (see below) to DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER or READ_FRAMEBUFFER. The binding is effected by calling
>
> ```
> void BindFramebuffer( enum target, uint framebuffer );
> ```

with target set to the desired framebuffer target and framebuffer set to the framebuffer object name. The resulting framebuffer object is a new state vector ...

Comment: So, if I really understood the purpose of glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffer(). I can, in a case of a FBO with multiple color buffer, choose in which color buffer the colors are actually written ?

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans Yes, and the frame buffer has not to be bound, because you name it, in compare to `glDrawBuffer`, which affects the currently bound frame buffer.